Is a function whose graph is central symmetric with respect to any point always linear?
If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)-f(x-h)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}, h \geq 0$, must $f$ be of the form $f(x)=ax+b$?
I originally thought to define $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x $ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=2x$ otherwise but this example does not really work since its graph is only centrally symmetric with respect to the origin. I then tried to see if it is possible to construct $f$ such that there exist three numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with the property that the points $(x_1, f(x_1)),(x_2, f(x_2)),(x_3, f(x_3))$ are not co-linear, and then consider the "smallest centrally symmetric graph generated by these points", but this did not work so well at the end. I feel like any non-trivial solution would involve some form of Axiom of Choice, but I am not sure how the construction would look like.

Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc
